# How to avoid "ls: write error: Broken pipe" with php exec

Tags: php

In PHP I am running this command:

```
exec ("ls -U ".$folder." |head -1000", $ls_u);
```

This command is inside a PHP file, run directly by PHP on the console and throws this error:

```
ls: write error: Broken pipe
```

What causes this error?  Or is using pipes in PHP exec not a good idea?

Answer (score 3):

**In Linux with PHP on the terminal, you can reproduce this error with this code:**

main.php:

```
<?php
  $process = popen("ls", "r");
  pclose($process);
?>
```

**Then running it like this on the terminal:**

```
eric@dev ~ $ php main.php
ls: write error: Broken pipe
```

The error happens because you are running a command which returns data and you are not catching it, so it complains about a broken pipe.

**I was able to fix it like this:**

```
<?php
  $handle = popen('ls', 'r');
  $read = fread($handle, 2096);
  pclose($handle);
  echo $read;
?>
```

**Then it works, printing:**

```
eric@dev ~ $ php main.php
main.php
anotherfile.txt
```

Note, you'll have to stick the `fread(...)` in a loop if you want to get all the output from ls.

Comment: Worth noting that you use `feof()` to determine whether there's any more input to be returned from `fread()`.

Answer (score -1):

I believe there's a syntax error in the console command, and suggest escaping the arguments with [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg).

```
exec('ls -U '.escapeshellarg($folder).' | head -1000', $ls_u);
```